# Excel If Statement with Wildcards and Value Search

Tags: excel, if-statement, wildcard, data-analysis

I have a bunch of data with flight arrival and departure times that I would like to categorize. For example, the data may say things like "On Time", "34 Minutes Early", "7 Minutes Late", etc. I would like to simply categorize if the flight was early, late or on time. The following formula has worked to achieve this goal: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Late*",E3)),"Late",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Early*",E3)),"Early",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*On Time*",E3)),"On Time","")))`

However, given that there exists a practical purpose to my analysis, I would like to count anything that is within 10 minutes of its scheduled arrival or departure time as "on time". I have tried variations of the following formulas `=IF(COUNTIF(E19,"*<10*"),"On Time","")` `=IF(COUNTIF(E19,"<"&"*10*"),"On Time","")`  which would then be put into my nested `IF` Statement above, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance / much appreciated fam :)

Comment: Can you post a copiable data using the Markdown Table Generator and show the expected output you need, so it helps to post a solution. Also please specifiy if there is no excel constraints, i.e you are using MS365 right?

Comment: extract number, if <= 10 put blank,  if number >10 put number and  late *-1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try this:

```
IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(LEFT(B2,2)*1,"")<=10,"",IFERROR(LEFT(B2,2)*1,""))*IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("*lat*",B2,1),0)=1,-1,1),"")
```

See:
[image]

Made an assumption that the number will only be minutes, but you can expand (and learn) if you have to edit for hours as well.

Edit: the use of iferror() explained: The first one just tidies up and leaves the relevant numerical result. the second and third deals with trying to multiply letters by 1... The last one deals with a failed search.

Comment: Can we reduce the no of `IFERROR()`s

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya try and see.

Comment: I know it will work, but I am asking will it be possible to minimize the use of `IFERROR()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya which is why I suggested you try. The first one just tidies up and leaves the relevant numerical result. the second and third deals with trying to multiply letters by 1... The last one deals with a failed search... What do you think from your testing?

Comment: Sir: `=LET(x,LEFT(B2,2)/1,
y,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("late",B2)),
IFERROR(IF(XOR(x<=10,y),x*-1,IF(x<=10,"",x)),""))` or `=LET(x,LEFT(B2,2)/1,
y,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("late",B2)),
IFERROR(IF(AND(x>10,y),x*-1,IF(x<=10,"",x)),""))`

Comment: Sir your formula works perfect, i just tried to make it short

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya so you have 204 characters, I have 115. However, you use iferror() twice and isnumber() twice while I used iferror() 4 times... A difficult thing to solve but nice to see another solution. Consider posting it as an answer, worth my vote.

Comment: No Sir, this is one formula `=LET(x,LEFT(B2,2)/1, y,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("late",B2)), IFERROR(IF(XOR(x<=10,y),x*-1,IF(x<=10,"",x)),""))`

Comment: Sir this is another `=LET(x,LEFT(B2,2)/1, y,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("late",B2)), IFERROR(IF(AND(x>10,y),x*-1,IF(x<=10,"",x)),""))`

Comment: `ISNUMBER()` & `IFERROR()` is once used only. No Sir not posting, as you already have posted a working solution. and string length with `XOR()` is `101` while with `AND()` is `100`